# Missing file changes on git repository

Tags: git

I've encountered a situation where certain file changes appear to be missing in the latest version of the master branch in our Git repository.

When I run the `git log --stat` command, I can observe that a file was modified with 1 insertion and 90 deletions in a commit made on June 21, 2023.
However, when I use the `git log filename` command to specifically track changes to that file, the last change I can find is from a commit made on April 10, 2023.

Our repository has multiple merged branches, and I've meticulously double-checked the branch, file path, and various other factors to confirm the accuracy of my findings.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: History simplification.

Comment: Also you're giving the command wrong. Try `git log --all -- filename`

Comment: The command `git log --all -- filename` shows the April 10, 2023 commit , and other commit from August 31, but is in another branch (is not in master).. It not seems history simplification. Thanks @matt

Comment: Are there another theory ?

Comment: So you tried `git log --all --full-history -- filename` and your target commit did not appear in the list?